# How to combine number data and image data for training in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

so, for example, I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import tensorflow as tf

data = [2.78,1.78]
y = [1]
img = cv.imread("path/to/image")
data.append(img)
data_array = np.array(data)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, input_shape=(3,), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')
    ])

model.compile(loss='sparse_categoricalcrossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(data_array, y, epochs=100)
```

When I try to run this code, it raise this error

```
ValueError: Failed to find data adapter that can handle input: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>, (<class 'list'> containing values of types {"<class 'int'>"})
```

Is there anyway to combine those two data (data and img) for training?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data going into the neural network must have a homogeneous format; you can't feed it an integer sometimes, and then an image. The shape of the data going into the network must remain the same. Here you put the shape as `(3,)`, which is incorrect―that's simply the *length* of the array you're passing. The `shape` argument refers instead to the dimension of an individual data point, e.g., a 100x100 RGB image could have shape `(100,100,3)`.

So, the simplest way to combine image and integer data would be to append an integer to a flat array representing an image. This would probably not work very well, but would at least compile.

A **better approach** is to architect this in such a way that the integer doesn't get drowned out by raw image data. Perhaps this means running the images through a convnet to get a [feature vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_(machine_learning)#Extensions), appending the corresponding integer to it, then feeding that to another net. But this would depend on the specifics of what you're trying to do.

Comment: so is it maybe okay to load the image and do numpy.flatten to it, then appending the integer data into the flatten array that i've just created?

Comment: You can certainly try that, and it will train, but I wouldn't expect it to work very well

Comment: Thank you very much, it works pretty well, though

Comment: Glad to hear that :)